# No jquery... Javascript highlights one table row at a time, now how can I change the background color based on user input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a complete code segment that allows me to change the background color of one row. It toggles all of the background colors off and then toggles the collor for the row you clicked on by changing the class of the element.

```
JS: 
function selected(){
    var index,
      table = document.getElementById("dps");
  for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
        if(typeof index !== "undefined"){
          table.rows[index].classList.toggle("selected");
      }
      console.log(typeof index);
      index = this.rowIndex;
      this.classList.toggle("selected");
      console.log(typeof index);
    };
  }
}
selected();
CSS: 
.selected {background-color: grey;}
```

Now, I'm looking to change the background color based on user input. If the user clicks one of three buttons that are not directly connected to the table at all it needs to change background to red, purple, and blue respectively. Ideally, this would work both ways. The user clicks the table first and sees a grey background, clicking the buttons will change the background accordingly, while a different user can click on the button first and then the table causing the prefered background to be in place. I've tried a few methods but I'm really unsure of the best way to do this WITHOUT using jquery. [Here's my failed attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/M4V3R1C8/23bLf4vc/) It focusses on getting the classname and then toggles the desired classname in while toggling out the undesired name. Of course, for this method to work users would have to click the table first and then the buttons when I want the code to work either way.

Comment: you could use a global variable to store the highlight color or the classname that defines that highlight color.

when you change the color with these 3 buttons you update the global variable and run the function that sets the class on the table row /column

Comment: Please fix the console errors. Start by not mixing jQuery syntax with plain JS: it is `onclick = function() { ` and not `onClick(function { ` - and no end parenthesis:

`document.getElementById("blue").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('selected')[0].classList.toggle("blue").classList.toggle("selected");
  }`

Comment: This works better but only if you click a row first. You do not have a test for the selected returns a row or not: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/d6bagtrq/ - I also had to fix your HTML

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: PS: If you want users on different browsers to highlight and see other highligts, you will need to ajax and save the click and pull this knowledge on the other browsers

Comment: Thanks a ton, it definitely helps me move forward.

Comment: Add a jsFiddle please.